# Why does my Teleport Move not function the way I want it to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing my Computer Science A-Level NEA and I want to program a teleport for my player character to use in these circumstances:

1. The direction of the teleport is controlled by the left mouse button
2. The player can only teleport once until they touch the ground again
3. If the player teleports through enemies then those enemies will be instantly killed.

The third one isn't too important at the moment as the 2nd condition isn't working properly.

> using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using
> UnityEngine;
>
> public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour {
> public Vector2 screenPosition;
> public Vector2 worldPosition;
>
> ```
> private CharacterController2D characterController2D;
>
> public bool canTeleport = true;
>
> void Awake()
> {
>     characterController2D = GetComponent<CharacterController2D>();
> }
>
> public void t_PORT()
> {
>     bool ground_check = characterController2D.m_Grounded;
>     if (canTeleport = true && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
>     {
>         screenPosition = Input.mousePosition;
>
>         worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);
>
>         transform.position = worldPosition;
>
>         while (ground_check = false)
>         {
>             if (ground_check = false)
>             {
>                 canTeleport = false;
>             }
>
>             else
>             {
>                 canTeleport = true;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

Here is the code for the teleport. It works by taking the on-screen position of the mouse when clicked, translating it into an in-game position and changing the player's position to that of the  mouse's.

I took a boolean value from my Character Controller called m_grounded which checks to see if the player is currently touching the ground. I thought that if the player has already teleported I could use a while loop (it would loop on the condition that m_grounded is false and break when the player touches the ground allowing them to teleport again). The first time I tried this it didn't work as I had the code in an Update Class and when I would teleport the game would freeze. I then put it into it's own class called t_Port (which you can see above) but then the player wouldn't teleport at all. I decided to put it in a FixedUpdate class which allowed the player to teleport once more but the player could teleport an infinite amount of times (which I do not want).

The script for my character controller is here:

> using UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.Events;
>
> public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour {  [SerializeField]
> private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          // Amount
> of force added when the player jumps.     [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField]
> private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;          // Amount of maxSpeed
> applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%   [Range(0, .3f)]
> [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;  // How
> much to smooth out the movement   [SerializeField] private bool
> m_AirControl = false;                         // Whether or not a
> player can steer while jumping;   [SerializeField] private LayerMask
> m_WhatIsGround;                          // A mask determining what is
> ground to the character   [SerializeField] public Transform
> m_GroundCheck;                           // A position marking where
> to check if the player is grounded.   [SerializeField] private
> Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          // A position
> marking where to check for ceilings   [SerializeField] private
> Collider2D m_CrouchDisableCollider;                // A collider that
> will be disabled when crouching
>
> const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle
> to determine if grounded  public bool m_Grounded;            //
> Whether or not the player is grounded.    const float k_CeilingRadius =
> .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can
> stand up  private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;  private bool
> m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is
> currently facing.     private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;
>
> [Header("Events")]  [Space]
>
> public UnityEvent OnLandEvent;
>
> [System.Serializable]   public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent { }
>
> public BoolEvent OnCrouchEvent;     private bool m_wasCrouching = false;
>
> private void Awake()    {       m_Rigidbody2D =
> GetComponent();
>
> ```
>   if (OnLandEvent == null)            OnLandEvent = new UnityEvent();
>
>   if (OnCrouchEvent == null)          OnCrouchEvent = new BoolEvent();    }
> ```
>
> public void FixedUpdate()   {       bool wasGrounded = m_Grounded;
> m_Grounded = false;
>
> ```
>   // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck
> ```
>
> position hits anything designated as ground       // This can be done
> using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project
> settings.         Collider2D[] colliders =
> Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius,
> m_WhatIsGround);      for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)      {
> if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)          {
> m_Grounded = true;
> if (!wasGrounded)
> OnLandEvent.Invoke();           }       }   }
>
> public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)    {       // If
> crouching, check to see if the character can stand up         if (!crouch)
> {           // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing
> up, keep them crouching           if
> (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius,
> m_WhatIsGround))          {
> crouch = true;          }       }
>
> ```
>   //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
>   if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)         {
>
>       // If crouching             if (crouch)             {
>           if (!m_wasCrouching)
>           {
>               m_wasCrouching = true;
>               OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(true);
>           }
>
>           // Reduce the speed by the crouchSpeed multiplier
>           move *= m_CrouchSpeed;
>
>           // Disable one of the colliders when crouching
>           if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
>               m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = false;            }           else            {
>           // Enable the collider when not crouching
>           if (m_CrouchDisableCollider != null)
>               m_CrouchDisableCollider.enabled = true;
>
>           if (m_wasCrouching)
>           {
>               m_wasCrouching = false;
>               OnCrouchEvent.Invoke(false);
>           }           }
>
>       // Move the character by finding the target velocity            Vector3
> ```
>
> targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
> // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
> m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity,
> targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);
>
> ```
>       // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing
> ```
>
> left...           if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)             {
> // ... flip the player.
> Flip();             }           // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...           else if (move < 0 &&
> m_FacingRight)            {
> // ... flip the player.
> Flip();             }       }       // If the player should jump...         if (m_Grounded && jump)         {           // Add a vertical force to the player.
> m_Grounded = false;             m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f,
> m_JumpForce));        }   }
>
> private void Flip()     {       // Switch the way the player is labelled as
> facing.       m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;
>
> ```
>   // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.       Vector3 theScale =
> ```
>
> transform.localScale;         theScale.x *= -1;       transform.localScale =
> theScale;     } }

And here is my Player Movement script:

> using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using
> UnityEngine;
>
> public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
>
> ```
> public CharacterController2D controller;
> public Animator animator;
>
> float X_Speed = 0.0f;
> float Y_Speed = 0.0f;
> float Ground_speed = 0.0f;
> float Ground_angle;
>
> float acceleration_speed = 0.46875f;
> float deceleration_speed = 5.0f;
> float friction_speed = 0.66875f;
> float top_speed = 100.0f;
>
> public bool jump = false;
> bool crouch = false;
>
>
> // Update is called once per frame
> void Update()
> {
>
>     if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0) //if player is pressing left
>     {
>         if (X_Speed > 0.0f)
>         {
>             X_Speed -= deceleration_speed; //decelerate
>
>             if (X_Speed <= 0.0f)
>             {
>                 X_Speed = -0.5f;
>             }
>         }
>
>         else if (X_Speed > -top_speed)
>         {
>             X_Speed -= acceleration_speed; //accelerate
>             if (X_Speed <= -top_speed)
>             {
>                 X_Speed = -top_speed; //impose top speed limit
>             }
>         }
>
>     }
>
>     if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0) //if player is pressing right
>     {
>         if (X_Speed < 0.0f) //if moving to the left
>         {
>             X_Speed += deceleration_speed; //decelerate
>             if (X_Speed >= 0.0f)
>             {
>                 X_Speed = 0.5f;
>             }
>         }
>
>         else if (X_Speed < top_speed)
>         {
>             X_Speed += acceleration_speed; //accelerate
>             if (X_Speed >= top_speed)
>             {
>                 X_Speed = top_speed; //impose top speed limit
>             }
>         }
>         
>     }
>
>     if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0)
>     {
>         X_Speed -= friction_speed; //decelerate
>         if (X_Speed <= 0)
>         {
>             X_Speed = 0.0f;
>         }
>     }
>
>     animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(X_Speed));
>
>     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
>     {
>         jump = true;
>         animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
>     }
>
>     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
>     {
>         crouch = true;
>     }
>     else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
>     {
>         crouch = false;
>     }
> }
>
> private void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
> {
>
> }
>
> public void OnLanding()
> {
>     animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
> }
>
> public void OnCrouching(bool isCrouching)
> {
>     animator.SetBool("isCrouching", isCrouching);
> }
>
> void FixedUpdate()
> {
>     // Move the character, jump and croutch
>     controller.Move(X_Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
>     jump = false;
> } }
> ```

I would like for my player character to teleport once before having to touch the ground to be able to teleport again.

Comment: Could you format your question a little bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my problems:

> using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using
> UnityEngine;
>
> public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour {
> public Vector2 screenPosition;
> public Vector2 worldPosition;
>
> ```
> private CharacterController2D characterController2D;
>
> public bool canTeleport = true;
>
> void Awake()
> {
>     characterController2D = GetComponent<CharacterController2D>();
> }
>
> void FixedUpdate()
> {
>     if (canTeleport == true && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
>     {
>
>         T_Port();
>     }
>
>     else
>     {
>         bool ground_check = characterController2D.m_Grounded;
>
>         if (!ground_check && canTeleport == false)
>         {
>             canTeleport = false;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             canTeleport = true;
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> public void T_Port()
> {
>     screenPosition = Input.mousePosition;
>    
>     worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);
>    
>     transform.position = worldPosition;
>
>     canTeleport = false;
> }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the thouroughness of posting all relevant code, but the error is in the very first snippet:

```cs
while (ground_check = false)
{
    if (ground_check = false)
    {
        ...
```

One equals sign is an assignment, two is an equality check:

```cs
while (ground_check == false)
{
    if (ground_check == false)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: Also worth noting that when using variables that are already booleans, equality and inequality comparisons are unnecessary. `someVariable == true` is the same as just `someVariable` the equality comparison with `true` is entirely meaningless. And `someVariable == false` is the same as `!someVariable`.

Comment: Completely true, but this more so illustrates the point.

Comment: This still doesn't fix the problem